# Font not found by JasperReports when built with Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, fonts, jasper-reports

I've had to add a non-standard font (called "Ovo") to a JasperReports project I'm working on and have followed all the directions (such as [here](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/541641/font-not-available-jvm)) to export the font to a .jar from iReport and added it to my build path in Eclipse. This works fine when I compile the project with eclipse.

Now I'm moving to production and have been compiling the project on the command line with Maven (v3.0.4) using the *mvn clean install* command, so eclipse is totally out of the build cycle. I've installed the font jar to my local maven repo and added it as a dependency in my pom (similar to as described [here](http://grysz.com/2010/06/01/use-custom-fonts-in-jasperreports-pdf-exporter/)) but then I run the program and when the code that generates the document which uses that font executes I get a [JRFontNotFoundException](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/util/JRFontNotFoundException.html).

I've checked my local repo and my pom and made sure that the jar is there and that the pom identies it properly. I've also checked my maven build path with *mvn dependency:build-classpath* and also looked at my *mvn install* output. The path to the font jar appears in both and there are no errors thrown.

I'm out of ideas. Why doesn't this font jar work when the project is compiled with maven on the CLI but works no problem when I compile it in eclipse? (It is a maven project in eclipse too, so the .classpath pretty much just says 'use maven')

Here is the command I used to install the jar in my local repo:

```
    mvn install:install-file -Dfile=jFreeChartFonts.jar -DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=jFreeChartFont -Dversion=0.0.1 -Dpackaging=jar
```

And here is the dependency declaration in the pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>jFreeChartFonts</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I've also tried setting the scope to runtime instead of compile, but this makes no difference.

Comment: Did you check the *font's jar* in maven repo?  Maybe it is broken. Did you try to use this *jar* (from maven repo) in your first application (you described in the first part of your post)?

Comment: I just checked it against the original but as far as I can tell they are identical; they contain the same files and the files are all the same sizes. The only difference I can see is that in the repo the version has been appended to the filename. I removed the original external jar dependency from my build path path in eclipse when I added the maven dependency (I've cleaned, and updated the maven project too) so when I build from eclipse it is using the one in the maven repo afaik. When I build from eclipse this way, it works fine. But with mvn, it's a no go.

Comment: I guess the question can summarized as either:
A) What is the difference between building a maven project with mvn and building it in eclipse?
and/or
B) How can I find out more of the build details of each so I can examine the difference more closely and perhaps spot the source of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

in lib jasperreport: open .jar
open: net/sf/jasperreports/fonts
you see: just folder font name 'pictonic' exist
and config of file: 'jasperreports-fonts.xml'

```
<fontFamily name="Pictonic" visible="false">
        <normal>
            <ttf>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/pictonic/pictonic.ttf</ttf>
            <svg>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/pictonic/pictonic.svg</svg>
            <eot>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/pictonic/pictonic.eot</eot>
            <woff>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/pictonic/pictonic.woff</woff>
        </normal>
        <pdfEncoding>Identity-H</pdfEncoding>
        <pdfEmbedded>true</pdfEmbedded>
    </fontFamily>
```

copy folder dejavu have: DejaVuSans.ttf,DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf,...
to 'net/sf/jasperreports/fonts'
and add to config file: 'jasperreports-fonts.xml'

```
<fontFamily name="DejaVu Sans">
...
</fontFamily>
```

END rebuild MAVEN -> is success!

Comment: There's no `/fonts` folder in jasperreports JAR. It comes in a separate JAR, jasperreports-fonts.